# How php handle multiple request for file write

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have one pdf file which will written on every http request by single php script and I will count page of that pdf file.  So it is possible that file written by script came in race condition

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Try [flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

Comment: Actually I am using laravel so how can I use flock function in it

Comment: flock() is a PHP function and it will be available. Laravel is built on PHP only.

Comment: flock() require $file_id but on laravel storage::put()  donot give any file id

Comment: It requires a file pointer resource which you can get using fopen(). If you are looking for a wrapper of this in PSR-4 style, you can try searching on packagist.org that handles race condition and use it using composer install

Comment: Use either [flock()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock) as already suggested or use [tmpfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile) to avoid race conditions. I would suggest `tmpfile()`, because it is not blocking resources and may be more performant.